# Euler-Lagrange Equations for Molecular Dynamics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hilbert-space, notation, molecular-dynamics

In the [Car-Parrinello (CP) method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car%E2%80%93Parrinello_molecular_dynamics) for molecular dynamics simulation, the Euler-Lagrange equations are given as

> $$
> \begin{aligned} \frac { d } { d t } \frac { \partial \mathcal { L } _ { \mathrm { CP } } } { \partial \left\langle \dot { \psi } _ { i } \right| } & = \frac { \partial \mathcal { L } _ { \mathrm { CP } } } { \partial \left\langle \psi _ { i } \right| }.\end{aligned}
> $$

Why are we using the bra-vectors of the basis functions $\left\langle \psi _ { i } \right|$ here, instead of the ket vectors?

Comment: Is it because we usually denote $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ as a row vector and bra vectors are equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: It doesn't matter if you start with bra- or ket-vectors..

$\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle #1 \rvert}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert #1 \rangle}
 \newcommand{\LCP}[0]{\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{CP}}}$
Longer answer:

When you set up the Euler-Langrange equation for the bra-vectors $\bra{\psi_i}$
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial\LCP}{\partial\bra{\dot{\psi_i}}}
= \frac{\partial\LCP}{\partial\bra{\psi_{i}}},$$
then you get differential equations for the time-evolution of the ket-vectors $\ket{\psi_i(t)}$.

On the other hand, when you chose to set up the Euler-Langrange equations
for the ket-vectors $\ket{\psi_i}$
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial\LCP}{\partial\ket{\dot{\psi_i}}}
= \frac{\partial\LCP}{\partial\ket{\psi_{i}}},$$
then you get differential equations for the time-evolution of the bra-vectors $\bra{\psi_i(t)}$.

You can work out the details and see:
In the end the differential equations for $\ket{\psi_i(t)}$
and $\bra{\psi_i(t)}$ look the same.
Hence you can freely choose which one you prefer
(by convention most people prefer the differential equations for the ket-vectors).
The physical results from both are the same.